# Affine vs Projective curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $\mathbb A^n_k$ be affine $n$-space and let $\mathbb P^n_k$ be the projective $n$-space.

An **affine curve** is a set of the form $$C_f(k):=\{(a_1, \ldots, a_n)\in\mathbb A^n_k: f(a_1, \ldots, a_n)=0\}$$ where $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is non-constant.

A **projective curve** is a set of the form $$P_f(k):=\{(a_1:....: a_{n+1}): f(a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1})=0\}$$ where $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]$ is non-constant.

Every $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ produces an homogeneous polynomial ${}^hf\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]$ via $${}^h f(x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}):=x_{n+1}^{\textrm{deg}(f)}\cdot f(x_1/x_{n+1}, \ldots, x_n/x_{n+1}).$$ Conversely, every homogeneous $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]$ induces a polynomial ${}^d f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ via $${}^d f(x_1, \ldots, x_n):=f(x_1, \ldots, x_n, 1).$$

There are two natural questions:

1) Given $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n}]$, how does $C_f(k)$ relate to $P_{{}^h f}(k)$?

2) Given $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]$ homogeneous, how does $P_f(k)$ relate to $C_{{}^d f}(k)$?

I presume it works as follows:

There is an inclusion $$\imath: \mathbb A^n_k\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^n_{k}$$ given by $$\imath(a_1, \ldots, a_n):=(a_1: \ldots: a_n: 1).$$

Then:

Answer to 1) $\imath(C_f(k))=\imath(\mathbb A^n_k)\cap P_{{}^h f}(k)$. In particular, there is an identification $$C_f(k)\simeq \imath(\mathbb A^n_k)\cap P_{{}^h f}(k).$$

Answer to 2) I conjecture that $$P_f(k)\simeq C_{{}^d f}(k)\sqcup \{\mathcal{O}\}$$ where $\mathcal{O}\not\in C_{{}^d f}(k)$.

Are my answers to 1 and 2 correct?

Maybe my answer to 2) doesn't work always. I guess there must be a condition we must impose on $z_{n+1}$. In that case, what would it be the correct answer to 2)?

Thanks.

Comment: For it to be a (union of affine ie. irreducible) curves you need $n=2$, for $n=3$ it is a surface. And in general your $\{O\}$ is finitely many points, not only one (the remaining points of the projective completion of $f(x,y) = 0$ with $f(x,y) \in k[x,y]$ are the roots $(0,z_j)$ of $g(w,z)=w^a z^b f(1/w,1/z)$)

Comment: Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Do you have any reference which discuss that @reuns?

Comment: For $k$ an algebraically closed field and $(f(X,Y))$ a non-zero prime ideal of $k[X,Y]$ then $V((f))=\{ (x,y) \in k^2,f(x,y) = 0\}$ is an affine curve, you can take $x \in k$ as you want there are always finitely many solutions for $y$. If $(F(X,Y,Z))$ is a non-zero prime ideal of $k[X,Y,Z]$ then $V((F))$ is a surface, you can take $x,y \in k^2$ as you want there are always finitely many solutions for $z$. It corresponds to the number of transcendental elements needed to generated the function field $Frac(k[X,Y,Z]/(F(X,Y,Z)))$

Comment: @reuns Can I say that $P_f(k)\simeq C_{{}^d f}(k)\sqcup P_{f_0}(k)$ where $f_0(x_1, \ldots, x_n):=f(x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0)$? Or even better, $P_f(k)\simeq C_{{}^d f}(k)\sqcup C_{{}^df_p}(k)$ where ${}^d f_p$ is the homogeneous component of degree $p$ of ${}^d$ (where I'm supposing $\textrm{deg}(f)=p$)?

Answer (score 2):

Subtle issues arise when you do this kind of homogenizing and dehomogenizing. It's not so straightforward. In my opinion the best introductory explanation of all this can be found in the brilliant book [Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-16721-3). Go through chapter $8$ section $2$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out?